# JSON, JavaScript, wrong Japanese Character

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have this on my JSON-file (mydata.json on the server):

```
    "jp": [ "私はあなたを愛しています！",
```

and more. There is also "de" and "en" and so on and it is displayed correctly. But with these japanese characters, I get these unrecognizable characters. I have read threads here but I can't find a solution. I think it has something to do with the data from the server, wrong asking header, but don't know, how to fix it. I tried this (found here on stackoverflow) (file.js):

```
    $.ajax({url: myURL, contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(dataJSON){        
        console.log(dataJSON); 
            }
    });
```

End the outputs of the "de" and "en" (and more) are great, but the japanese characters appear like this:

```
���͂��Ȃ��������Ă��܂��I
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What kind of header does your server side part of the AJAX call have?

Comment: From where u fetch these data? if from Db, how it is stored in Db.

Comment: In java side :String str = "私はあなたを愛しています！";
    str = new String(str.getBytes("8859_1"), "UTF-8");

Comment: Ah thank you! When I wrote the mydata.json on my server I had to change the coding of the file to Shift-JIS, because there only show me cryptical instead of japanese characters. Now I have changed it (I thought they will disappear, but they don't) to UTF-8 and now it works. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

In the server you need unicode http://unicode-table.com/en/#cjk-radicals-supplement
In javascript there is no problem because it uses unicode

Comment: Thank you! Yes I changed the coding and now it works. Interesting site by the way.

Answer (score 0):

set Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
at the  beginning of the the file you request json from it

Answer (score 0):

Try this! 
Ajax automatically detects the dataType, but here it is explicit.

```
$.ajax({
    url: myURL, 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(dataJSON){        
       console.log(dataJSON); 
    }
});
```